# Association between 3 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like a user be able to create a course(so it should belong to one user) and also be able to join another course that it haven't created by him.What is the proper associations between the course and the user ? I want to make the following model associations:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :comments ,through: :courses
end

Class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users    #here i am not sure
  has_many :comments
end

Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :courses
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you should be able to do something like:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :course_users
  has_many :subscribed_courses, through: :course_users, source: :course # I think you should be able to do foreign_key: :course_id, class_name: 'Course'
  has_many :comments ,through: :courses
end

Class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :course_users
  has_many :participants, through: :course_users, source: :user # I think you should be able to do foreign_key: :user_id, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :comments
end

Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :courses
end

#course_users is a join table for courses and users
class CourseUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  # inside here you could have several other connections e.g grade of a user in a course within this join model
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
end
```

Comment: ok i understand what you say but how can i show comments from a course by all users ? Course.comments ?

Comment: About subscribed_courses and participants ,should i create seperate models ?No ,right ?Should i define them in any controller ?

Comment: if you want to show all comments on on all courses that was created by a particular user though, you'd need to do another `has_many :course_comments, through: :courses, source: :comments`

Comment: No, you wouldn't need a new model for those. You only need a join table/model which I described above as `CourseUser` following the convention.

Comment: To fetch all participants of a course, you can do: `course.participants` which should give you the users subscribed and `user.subscribed_courses` should give you all the courses a user has subscribed to

Comment: let's say that i want to show all comments by a user. how should i call it ?

Comment: Thank you for your response and time.Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're saying - you need to have a third model - you can call it enrollment

For Course you would use `belongs_to :user` if each course is created as a user.

Your Enrollment model with have two HABTAM

```
Class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
end
```

(An Aside, if a course is going to be offered more than once, you'll have to add an additional model for each instance of the course and the enrollment will belong to that model, and not courses)

Comment: So it's not possible to have 3 models ?and also how can i show all comments from a course or should i use enrollment ?thank you for your answer

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'have 3 models' - you can have as many models as you want - if you wish to do it with ONLY 3 models - that's complicated.  As for comments belonging to a course it depends on how they're going to be used and if courses will vary between instances.  If the course is always the same, taught the same, same teacher, same syllabus, then link the comments to the course.  If your course instances are different than the comments should be linked to the instances, it all depends on your planned implementation.